# How to create Azure Search Index using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cli

I am unable to find a way to use Azure CLI to create Azure Search index, I was able to create Azure Search service though.

Does any one know if there is way to create Azure Search Index using Azure CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data operations, including the management of indexes, are not currently (as of June 2021) exposed through the control plane command-line interface. Once you have a service provisioned, you can use the REST APIs exposed by that service to manage indexes, ingest data, and process queries. There are examples of calling the REST APIs from PowerShell [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-get-started-powershell). You can also use the [Azure SDK](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/) client libraries for .NET, JavaScript, Python, or Java.